# Example for creating Dropbutton

Tags: 8

I really want to implement Dropbutton in Drupal8
But I can't find any concrete example for that.

```
$db = array(
        array('#type' => 'dropbutton', '#links' =>
           array(
            'a' => array('title' => t('Google'), 'url' =>  Url::fromUri('http://www.google.com')),
            'b' =>array('title' => t('Yahoo'), 'url' =>  Url::fromUri('http://www.yahoo.com')))
        )
 );

 $buf = drupal_render($db);
```

`$buf` will contain some dropbutton wrapper element in HTML but it doesn't get rendered as dropbutton in the page.

Comment: try using `array('#type'=> 'dropbutton', 'links'=>array(your_array))`

Comment: I think you don't have to wrap your array with another array...

Comment: Btw. You should use `\Drupal::service('renderer')->renderRoot()` instead of `drupal_render()`.

Answer (score 2):

When using a Dropbutton in a form, there is documentation on the [class itself](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!lib!Drupal!Core!Render!Element!Dropbutton.php/class/Dropbutton/8.2.x) (since this question is over a year old, it may not have been there at the time) which matches the code above fairly closely (adjusted to match coding style would be something like):

```
$db = [
  '#type' => 'dropbutton', 
  '#links' => [
    'a' => [
      'title' => $this->t('Google'), 
      'url' =>  Url::fromUri('http://www.google.com'),
    ],
    'b' => [
       'title' => $this->t('Yahoo'), 
       'url' =>  Url::fromUri('http://www.yahoo.com'),
    ],
  ],
];
```

This assumes that you're inside a controller or similar class that has access to the t() function. The comment above is correct, you do not need the wrapping array, and will cause trouble unless it is also a proper render array (useful when putting the button into a table or other nested structure).

It also worth noting the links are an array valid for [`template_preprocess_links()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!includes!theme.inc/function/template_preprocess_links/8.2.x) and not a render element for a link which allows for attaching AJAX call backs as needed.

Comment: This worked PERFECTLY. Thanks so much for the clear, concise example!